# PHP returns results only if number < 10

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a simple example but I am not getting the expected results

```
    $a = '' ;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['a'])){
        if ((is_numeric($_REQUEST['a'])) < (10)){
            $a = 'show some text';
        }
    }
    echo $a;
```

This is all I have in the simple PHP file.
When I just open the page I get nothing as expected.

When I do ?a=1 I still get nothing.

But if I do ?a=a I get 'show some text'

Why is this?
I am expecting to only return 'show some text' if a < 10 I don't want anything to come back if a=text or it is a number > 10?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are comparing if true/false are less than 10. That's why. You never typecast anything nor do you compare integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, `is_numeric` return boolean

```
if (is_numeric($_REQUEST['a']) && $_REQUEST['a'] < 10) {
    $a = 'show some text';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is_numeric that you have used in if condition will return true or false
so if condition will get either 0 or 1 as result.

So use dual condition within if like below

```
if(is_numeric($_REQUEST['a'] && $_REQUEST['a']<10)
{
      //anything you need to do 
}
```

Thank you